# fetching images from gallery on android phones with internal storage

Tags: android, gridview, image-gallery, android-gallery

Hi I am developing an Android Gallery app where I am fetching images from built in gallery and displaying it.I am using the code as below

```
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};


   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Return all rows
                null,       
                null);


        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
        int size = cursor.getCount();
        // If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.
        if (size == 0) 
        {
            Log.e("size 0","0");
        }
```

The Problem is when I run this code on Phones having only internal storage (Galaxy Nexus) I am getting Log which says size as Zero even though there are images in built in gallery. How do I resolve this.
Please Help.Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

Comment: User media is accessed by EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI is only used by system apps.

Comment: I tried  EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and also INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, the EXTERNAL works fine on phones that have SD card, but doesn't work on phones like Galaxy Nexus (no external storage)

Comment: `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` is your URI. If thumbnail of the pic is not available then your query will return 0 data. So you query for the media instead of thumbnail.

Comment: I tried MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, this works fine but it is very slow in fetching even 5 pictures from Gallery! How to make fetch pictures fast like: MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Comment: First query for thumbnails, if it doesnt return anything then you can query for media.

Comment: In addition you can use cursor loader or async task to query the media.

Comment: That is the only option?

Comment: Check this app on Google play. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roidapp.photogrid&hl=en                                      where images are loaded so fast. How are they doing it? If I use MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI .                         The images are loaded too slow. Is there any other option.Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try queryMiniThumbnails??

Answer (score 4):

To get list of Gallery images you can try this

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN
};


Uri imageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;


Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(imageUri,
        projection, // Which columns to return
        null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
        null,       // Selection arguments (none)
        null        // Ordering
        );

Log.i("Images Count"," count="+cur.getCount());
```

Comment: managedQuery is deprecated. you should use getContentResolver().query(...) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try this on your button like "Browse"

```
   browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

         Intent i = new Intent(
                 Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                 android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                 startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

    }
});
```

and you cal also set selected image into your ImageView as

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

             imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.property_image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

}
```

In first block of code i use `startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);` this return result to called activity and we can get this result by second block of code, and set selected image in your ImageView

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
```

Replace `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` with `MediaStore.Images.MEDIA.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

```
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Return all rows
                null,       
                null);


    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    int size = cursor.getCount();
    // If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.
    if (size == 0) 
    {
        Log.e("size 0","0");
    }
```

---

**EDIT: Get the list of thumbnails and get the image URI from the cursor**

---

```
Uri uri=MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getContentUri("external");

 Cursor cursor=MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnails
      (getContentResolver(), uri, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,null);

if( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
    String uri = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA ) );
 }
```