# Retrieving all images from image gallery using content resolver in Android Studio [Java]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to grab all images from the image galley and display them in a grid view.  I'm stuck and don't know where to go from here.  If I run this code the cursor returns a getCount of 0.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    String[] imageStrings = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, imageStrings, null,
        null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);


    Log.d("onActivityCreated: ", cursor.getCount()+"");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If I run this code the cursor returns a getCount of 0.

Try changing `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to `MediaStore.Images.MEDIA.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

**Code modified**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            String[] imageStrings = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, imageStrings, null, 
                        null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);


           Log.d("onActivityCreated: ", cursor.getCount()+"");

    }
```

For more info check [@Tarun answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228831/4848308)

Hope this helps!!